# Creating new variable based on specific rows of other two variables in a long formatted dataset

Tags: r, dataframe, concatenation

I have a long dataset of emotional responses and I need to create a variable based on specific rows of two other variables, within subjects.

The following data frame includes data for two participants ("person") presented with 2 pictures (P1, P2, P3), each with 3 repetitions (R1, R2, R3) which is the "phase" variable. The variable response includes two things the rating for each presentation ( scale -30 to 30) and the emotion experienced per picture.

```
person <- c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2)
block <- c(4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5, 8, 8, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5, 8, 8)
phase <- c("P1R1", "P1R2", "P1R3", "P2R1","P2R2","P2R3", "Post1", "Post2","P1R1", 
    "P1R2", "P1R3", "P2R1","P2R2","P2R3", "Post1", "Post2")
response <- c(30, 30, 30, -30, -30, -30, "Happy", "Sad", 28, 27, 25, -23, -24,
    -22, "Excited", "Scared")
df <- data.frame(person, block, phase, emotion, response)
```

I need to create a new column that will be based on the block number and give me the emotion per picture.

I would like the new column to be called “postsurvey” and expect it to be as following:

```
postsurvey <-c ("Happy", "Happy", "Happy","Sad","Sad", "Sad", NA, NA, 
    "Excited", "Excited", "Excited", "Scared", "Scared", "Scared", NA, NA)
df <- data.frame(person, block, phase, emotion, response, postsurvey)
```

The code that I used is:

```
df<-df  %>% group_by(person, block) %>%
mutate(postsurvey=if(block==4){response[phase=="Post1"]}  
      else if (block==5){response[phase=="Post2"]} 
   else {print("NA")})
```

I expect for each subject to receive for each block number the same response, but what I get is that the response is not grouped by the subjects, and is not repeated within the subject by a block number, as if there is a vector of emotions and a person gets emotions that are not his.

*In my original data I have 4 pictures per subject with 10 repetitions, so the "else if" code repeated with more then two conditions.

Comment: Your sample code is not reproducible; `emotion` is not defined anywhere; ditto for `response` and `Emotions`. You also seem to use inconsistent column names: `block` vs. `blocknum`; `person` vs. `subject`. Also please add your expected output for the sample data you give.

Comment: Thank you, I have addressed these issues.

Comment: `Emotions` and `response` are still not defined anywhere. Still missing expected output too.

Comment: The new column's output would be as following:                                              
 postsurvey<-c("Happy", "Happy", "Happy","Sad","Sad", "Sad", NA, NA, "Excited", "Excited", "Excited", "Scared", "Scared", "Scared", NA, NA)